Allowing the user to move Path objects (Circles) added to a grid control
I have the following code that draws circles within a grid that I hoped would allow the user to dragmove the circles within it. Neither of the of events DragStarting, DropCompleted fire though. Do I need to enable something on the encompassing Grid? Any ideas where I'm going wrong?
public int DrawCircle(Brush colour, int strokeThickness, int x, int y, int width, int height, Grid cv)
    {
        Path c1 = new Path();
        c1.Stroke = colour;
        c1.Fill = transparentBrush;
        c1.StrokeThickness = strokeThickness;
        EllipseGeometry myEllipseGeometry = new EllipseGeometry();
        myEllipseGeometry.Center = new Point(x, y);
        myEllipseGeometry.RadiusX = height;
        myEllipseGeometry.RadiusY = width;
        c1.Data = myEllipseGeometry;


        DragGestureRecognizer dragGestureRecognizer = new DragGestureRecognizer();

        dragGestureRecognizer.CanDrag = true;
        dragGestureRecognizer.DragStarting += DragGestureRecognizer_DragStarting;
        dragGestureRecognizer.DropCompleted += DragGestureRecognizer_DropCompleted;

        c1.GestureRecognizers.Add(dragGestureRecognizer);
        //PanGestureRecognizer panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        //panGesture.PanUpdated += PanGesture_PanUpdated;
        //c1.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);

        cv.Children.Add(c1);

        return cv.Children.Count - 1;
    }

    private void DragGestureRecognizer_DropCompleted(object sender, DropCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void DragGestureRecognizer_DragStarting(object sender, DragStartingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

Thank you,
Mike

I think you should check this microsoft doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#enable-drag

I'm currently using Xamarin and not MAUI

Should be the same
